# Dimming feature on calendar

Tags: google-calendar

When using the "new look" in [Google calendar](http://www.google.com/calendar), I selected to dim past events; however, it dimmed today's events too. How can I keep today non-dimmed?

Comment: "Past events" means all events before now even if they took place today.

Answer (score 2):

`Today` shouldn't be dimmed. It should rather be "highlighted" like this:

[image: Calendar screenshot]

Be sure to check your **Calendar Settings**

- Click on the cogwheel in the top right
- Click on the **General** tab
- Check the `Your current time zone:` field.